# Multiple Column Dynamic Pivot Table

Tags: dynamic, pivot

I have a report to produce with the requirement of at December 2023 monthend our management need to see the sales from the previous financial years remaining months, so in December 2023 they want to see what sales were in January 2023, February 2023, March 2023 and April 2023.  At January 2024 monthend they need to see the sales from February 2023, March 2023 and April 2023.

I have data in a table and format below:

[image]

I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I have been using the code below which I stripped from another post but can't get it to work for my case:

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = N'';

SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME([MyPriorYearPeriod])
FROM (SELECT p.[MyPriorYearPeriod] FROM #MyTableToPivot AS p GROUP BY p.[MyPriorYearPeriod]) AS x;

SET @sql = N'
SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
SELECT [MyPriorYearPeriod], [Department], [Team], BilledFees FROM [#MyTableToPivot]
) AS j
PIVOT
(
SUM(BilledFees) FOR [MyPriorYearPeriod] IN ('

- STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
- ')
  ) AS p;';

PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

The result I get when running the code above is:

[image]

I can't get the Department and Team data in

I am hoping that there is a simple addition to t
his to get it working.  Any help and/or suggestion would be gratefully received.  Many thanks in advance